# WPF: Best method to render a WriteableBitmap if bitmap is frequently updated

Tags: wpf, bitmap

I'm currently implementing a broadband sonar display by using WriteableBitmap in WPF. 
A broadband sonar 'waterfall' display starts at the top and as time moves, the history data moves down and the first 'row' displays always the current situation.

Technically, I first move the content of the Bitmap down with WriteableBitmap.CopyPixels(), afterwards I update the Array to update the current line (top) of the Display.

My problem is now that - during update of the bitmap - the screen flickers. I've tried to write my own implementation of WritePixels:

```
 public static unsafe void WritePixels(WriteableBitmap writeableBitmap, BitmapProperties bitmapProperties)
    {

       writeableBitmap.Lock();
       IntPtr buff = writeableBitmap.BackBuffer;

       byte* pbuff = (byte*)buff.ToPointer();

        for (int i = 0; i < bitmapProperties.BitmapArray.Length; i += bitmapProperties.BytesPerPixel)
        {
            pbuff[i] = bitmapProperties.BitmapArray[i];
            pbuff[i + 1] = bitmapProperties.BitmapArray[i + 1];
            pbuff[i + 2] = bitmapProperties.BitmapArray[i + 2];
            pbuff[i + 3] = bitmapProperties.BitmapArray[i + 3];

        }

        writeableBitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, (int)writeableBitmap.Width, (int)writeableBitmap.Height));
        writeableBitmap.Unlock();

    }
```

Unfortunately the ouctome is the same.

I've seen here some similar questions (implementing a medical ultrasonic-display) but the usecase here is slightly different, since I get not the picture from a third party c++ interface but I 'draw' and copy the bitmap by myself (altering/copying the bitmap-array).
The rendering (update of the bitmap) shall take place every ~ 250 milliseconds.

What would my best choice here...working with a cached bitmap? I have not much experience when it comes to low-level bitmap operations in WPF (I am using WPF 4.5).

Thanks.

EDIT: I've compared it with a reference application, written in C++/DirectX: To my astonishment, I see the 'flickering' even there happening. It might be some optical effects, disturbing the eyes etc. Nevertheless, the question is still valid concerning if there is a better approach than my current implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried to measure if it just takes too long to refresh the whole image? Maybe double buffering can help you out then:

- Copy the whole bitmap
- Add the your changes or alternate the copy of the image in a background thread
- If the work is done, switch the prepared image from the background thread with the currently visible image
- Again make changes to the image currently not visible and so on...

Comment: Yes, have thought about that but have not tried it, yet. Will try to optimize it later...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use CopyMemory in kernel32.dll, which is faster

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "CopyMemory", SetLastError = false)]
public static extern void CopyMemory(IntPtr dest, IntPtr src, uint count);

private Data2Image(int width, int height, IntPtr data, WriteableBitmap)
{
    writeableBitmap.Lock();            
    try
    {
        CopyMemory(writeableBitmap.BackBuffer, data, (uint)(width * height * 4));
        writeableBitmap.AddDirtyRect(new Int32Rect(0, 0, width, height));
    }
    finally
    {
        writeableBitmap.Unlock();
    }
}
```